# go network traffic GRE encapsulation

Tags: go, networking, linux-kernel

I want to write an application using golang that will intercept any traffic from the NIC to an application and from the application to the nic running on the machine. For example, we are running an HTTP server.

This application will look into the packet, and if the packet has a GRE header from a specific IP, it will decapsulate the traffic and forward using the inner IP header. With traffic from the application to the NIC, I want to encapsulate the packet with a GRE header.

I have no idea where to start and need some advice.

Update my findings:

So I have the following:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "io"
        "net"
)

func main() {
        ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:8000")
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }

        for {
                conn, err := ln.Accept()
                if err != nil {
                        panic(err)
                }

                go handleRequest(conn)
        }
}

func handleRequest(conn net.Conn) {
        fmt.Println("new client")

        proxy, err := net.Dial("tcp", "10.10.1.1:80")
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }

        fmt.Println("proxy connected")
        go copyIO(conn, proxy)
        go copyIO(proxy, conn)
}

func copyIO(src, dest net.Conn) {
        defer src.Close()
        defer dest.Close()
        io.Copy(src, dest)
}
```

I believe that I have to have the logic in this `go copyIO(proxy, conn)` call.

Comment: This was the first thing that popped into my mind, not sure how much it will help: https://youtu.be/XqKvgzXCoXc

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to deal with tunneling on OS level and then to build your proxying logic on top of that instead of implementing the gre encap/decap in the code?

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret "intercept".